# PowerApps : Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am trying to send a post request using flow in powersapps it is not working and it giving always the same  error :"Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel." . however when i test it in postmap it is working.
in server side i open the conection just on one port 
as in the foto [image]

if i make the request to http not https i get :400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
any solution or suggtions?
thanks in advance

Comment: I am not very sure about this, but I remember I changed one of my flow from https to http and this helped. Would it be possible for you to give it a try?

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion in my case it will not work i found the problem
The problem is that flow validate the ssl key and if not valid it will not send it
i need just to send key with request but thanls for ur answer